# Custom Input Mappings JSON : Could not find any matches for the incoming event with JSONPath

Tags: json, mapping, event-receiver, wso2-cep

I have an event receiver with custom input mapping as my event format was a little different. It has no meta or correlation attributes. 
Example is:

```
{ "ts":"2016-05-08T08:59:47.363764Z",
  "uid":"CLuCgz3HHzG7LpLwH9",
  "id.orig_h":"172.30.26.119",
  "id.orig_p":51976,
  "id.resp_h":"172.30.26.160",
  "id.resp_p":22,
  "version":2,
  "client":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0",
  "server":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6",
  "cipher_alg":"arcfour256",
  "mac_alg":"hmac-md5",
  "compression_alg":"none",
  "kex_alg":"diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1",
  "host_key_alg":"ssh-rsa",
  "host_key":"8d:df:71:ac:29:1f:67:6f:f3:dd:c3:e5:2e:5f:3e:b4"}
```

There is no newline, I have added to make it readable. Accordingly I created an event receiver with a custom input mapping :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventReceiver name="sshlogreceiver" statistics="disable"
trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventreceiver">
<from eventAdapterType="http">
    <property name="transports">all</property>
</from>
<mapping customMapping="enable" type="json">
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.ts"/>
        <to name="ts" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.uid"/>
        <to name="uid" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.id.orig_h"/>
        <to name="id_orig_h" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.id.orig_p"/>
        <to name="id_orig_p" type="int"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.id.resp_h"/>
        <to name="id_resp_h" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.id.resp_p"/>
        <to name="id_resp_p" type="int"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.version"/>
        <to name="version" type="int"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.client"/>
        <to name="client" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.server"/>
        <to name="server" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.cipher_alg"/>
        <to name="cipher_alg" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.mac_alg"/>
        <to name="mac_alg" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.compression_alg"/>
        <to name="compression_alg" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.kex_alg"/>
        <to name="kex_alg" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.host_key_alg"/>
        <to name="host_key_alg" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from jsonPath="$.host_key"/>
        <to name="host_key" type="string"/>
    </property>
</mapping>
<to streamName="SSHInStream" version="1.0.0"/>
</eventReceiver>
```

The sample event of input stream is :

```
{
"event": {
    "payloadData": {
        "ts": "data5",
        "uid": "data5",
        "id_orig_h": "data1",
        "id_orig_p": 70,
        "id_resp_h": "data3",
        "id_resp_p": 4,
        "version": 50,
        "client": "data1",
        "server": "data2",
        "cipher_alg": "data5",
        "mac_alg": "data3",
        "compression_alg": "data3",
        "kex_alg": "data4",
        "host_key_alg": "data4",
        "host_key": "data4"
    }
}
}
```

I dont have `event` and `payload` tags in my events as it is a simple log file. When I try to send events, I got an error on console saying :

ERROR

```
{org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.type.json.JSONInputMapper} -  Could not find any matches for the incoming event with JSONPath : com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath@543abe49 ,hence dropping the event
```

Have I done custom input mapping wrong or what else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that error was the presence of dots (.) in my event's parameters. As soon as I replaced them with the other character, in my case i chose underscores, it worked fine.